# Normal Distribution question?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

> Consider tossing a fair coin `100n` times, where n is geometrically distributed with mean `6`. Due to a counting error, it is reported that the fraction of heads is in `[0.5, 0.51]`. What is the most likely value for `n`?

My professor calculated the value of n=3, but I have no idea how to get that. Can anyone explain ?

Comment: This question should be tagged as `[self-study]`, please also read http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: As pointed out in comments to the duplicate, the meaning of this question is obscure.

Answer (score 1):

First, do you know what your professor meant by "due to a counting error"? That seems like it could ruin any individual inferential step, making any argument shaky. I'm going to assume they meant something like "instead of reporting all of the summary, we report only a true portion of the summary."

The long way: we start off with a prior on $n$, that it is geometrically distributed with mean $6$. We then generate a number: $H$, the number of heads when a fair coin is flipped $100n$ times, which is a random variable with a binomial distribution $B(100n,0.5)$. From $H$, we then estimate the underlying propensity of the coin to land on heads, for which we'd use a beta distribution whose parameters are (heads+0.5, tails+0.5) if we use the [Jeffreys prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Bayesian_inference).

Finally, we have something that would make sense to report as $[0.5, 0.51]$, which is presumably the [credible interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval) or something associated with this beta distribution.

We can now calculate the likelihood for each value of $n$, and we can pick the highest one, which if your professor is correct is 3.

One might be able to use an approximation to get there faster--my attempts to jump straight to the variance of the beta distribution from knowing that the range is $[0.5, 0.51]$ got a number for $n$ considerably higher than 3, though, so it must be the case that they want the binomial distribution to be relevant.

Comment: +1 This is a valiant effort to make sense of the question.